# How do I check to see if an object implements ->__toString() in PHP?

Tags: php, string, object

Is there anyway to see if an object specifically implements ->__toString? This doesn't seem to work:

```
method_exists($object, '__toString');
```

Comment: What does method_exists return for your object?

Comment: That's odd, method_exists should be sufficient for doing this. For example you use method_exists to check if the __toString exist and print the instance or if you get false you use the get_class to print the name instead.

Comment: Ahh, i just wrote some test code and I think you are right. See my answer below

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two way to check it.

Lets assume you have classes:

```
class Foo
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return 'foobar';
    }
}

class Bar
{
}
```

Then you can do either:

```
$rc = new ReflectionClass('Foo');       
var_dump($rc->hasMethod('__toString'));

$rc = new ReflectionClass('Bar');       
var_dump($rc->hasMethod('__toString'));
```

or use:

```
$fo = new Foo;
var_dump( method_exists($fo , '__toString'));
$ba = new Bar;
var_dump( method_exists($ba , '__toString'));
```

Difference is that in first case the class is **not** actually instantiated.
You can look at demo here : http://codepad.viper-7.com/B0EjOK

Comment: There's no need for reflection or instantiation. You can pass the name of the class as the first parameter to `method_exists()` instead of an object of that class.

Answer (score 6):

Reflections is slow, and I think it's the worst solution to use them.

```
bool method_exists ( mixed $object , string $method_name )
```

object - An object instance or a class name (http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php)

There is no need to create an object to checking for existence of a method.

```
method_exists('foo', '__toString')
```

or

```
interface StringInterface{
   public function __toString() :string;
}


class Foo implement StringInterface {...}

->>(new MyClass) instanceof StringInterface
```

Answer (score 5):

You must be doing something wrong somewhere else, because this works:

```
class Test {

function __toString() {
    return 'Test';
}

}

$test = new Test();

echo method_exists($test, '__toString');
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use reflection: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.hasmethod.php

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 8 a new interface Stringable appears.
The `Stringable` interface can be used to type hint anything that is a string or implements `__toString()`. Furthermore, whenever a class implements `__toString()`, it automatically implements the interface behind the scenes and there's no need to manually implement it

```
class Foo
{
    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return 'foo';
    }
}

function bar(Stringable $stringable) { /* … */ }

bar(new Foo());
bar('abc');
```

ref:[source](https://stitcher.io/blog/new-in-php-8)